# creating watermarks in perl tk

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a Perl-Tk code and that code createas a GUI with 5 Tabs in it. My requirement is i need to insert a Image (logo) that should be a watermarking image and that should come in all the 5 Tabs. I searched in internet and there are no such ways available.

Does any one knows ??

Code is given below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Tk;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk::NoteBook;
use Tk::TextUndo;
use XML::Simple;
use IO::Socket::INET;

# ===================variables==================
my $fname;
my $open_fname;
my $f;
my $info;
my $t;
# my $load_file_variable;
my $types;
my $menubar;
my @path;
my $parser_path;
my $log_filename;
my $dut_conf_filename;
my $w;
my %info;
my @key;
my $sub_routine_flg = 0;
# ==============================================

$log_filename = '/home/SaLTT/Log/log.txt';
$dut_conf_filename = '/home/SaLTT/Log/dut_configuration.txt';

my $filename = '/home/sait11/Desktop/Examples/test.txt';
# print "\tfilename***$filename\n\n";

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
    $mw->optionAdd("*font", "-*-arial-normal-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*");
    $mw->optionAdd("*borderWidth", 3);
    $mw->geometry("1250x1250");
    $mw->title('SaLTT');

# ===================Adding Logo==================
    my $image = '/home/SaLTT/images/SAI_logo.gif';    # 32x32 GIF or BMP
    my $icon = $mw->Photo(-file => $image);
    $mw->iconimage($icon);
# ==============================================
    $menubar = $mw->Menu(-type => 'menubar');
    $mw->configure(-menu => $menubar);

####### Menus #######

    my $mfile = $menubar->cascade(-label => '~File', -tearoff => 0);    #   File_Menu
    my $mview = $menubar->cascade(-label => '~View', -tearoff => 0);    #   View_Menu  
    my $medit = $menubar->cascade(-label => '~Edit', -tearoff => 0);    #   Edit_Menu
    my $mhelp = $menubar->cascade(-label => '~Help', -tearoff => 0);    #   Help_Menu

# ==================== File ====================
    $mfile->command(    -label => '~Open',
                        -accelerator => 'Control+o',
                        -command => \&open_file
                    );
    $mfile->command(    -label => '~Save',
                        -accelerator => 'Control+s',
                        -command => \&save_log_file
                    );

# ==================== Edit ====================
    $medit->command(    -label => '~Edit',
                        -accelerator => 'Control+e',
                        -command => \&edit_file
                    );

# *************************************************
my $nb = $mw->NoteBook( )->pack( -expand => 1,
                                 -fill => 'both'
                                );
#=====================================================
# Page 1 on the notebook, with button on that page
#               DUT_Configuration
#=====================================================
my $tab1 = $nb->add('page1', -label => 'DUT_Configuration');
    $f = $tab1->Frame->pack(-side => 'bottom');
    $t = $tab1->Scrolled("TextUndo",-width => 600,-height => 400, -scrollbars => 'osoe')->pack(-side=>"right",
                                                                                               -expand => "yes",
                                                                                               -fill => "y"
                                                                                               );

    foreach (qw/IP_ADDRESS_SS PORT_NUMBER_CLIENT PROTOCOL_CLIENT/)
    {
        $w = $t->Label(-text => "$_:", -relief => 'groove', -width => 25);
        $t->windowCreate('end', -window => $w);
        $w = $t->Entry(-width => 20, -textvariable => \$info{$_})->pack();
        $t->windowCreate('end', -window => $w);
        $t->insert('end', "\n");
    }

    $f->Button(-text => 'Exit!',-activebackground=>"red", -command=>sub{exit})->pack( -side=>'right',
                                                                                     -anchor=>'se',
                                                                                     -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                                                   );
    $f->Button(-text => 'Save',-activebackground=>"green", -command=>\&print_dut_rec)->pack( -side=>'right',
                                                                                      -anchor=>'se',
                                                                                      -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                                                    );
    my $clear_text = $f->Button(-text => "Clear Text",-command => \&clear_entry)->pack(-side => 'right',
                                                                                      -anchor=>'se',
                                                                                      -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                                                      );
#=====================================================
# Empty page 2
# SS_Configuration
#=====================================================
my $tab2 = $nb->add('page2', -label => 'SS_Configuration');
$tab2->Button(-text => 'Exit!',-activebackground=>"red", -command=>sub{exit})->pack(  -side=>'bottom',
                                                            -anchor=>'se',
                                                            -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                          );
#=====================================================
# Empty page 3
# TC_Manager
#=====================================================
my $tab3 = $nb->add('page3', -label=>'TC_Manager');
$tab3->Button(-text=>"Test-UE", -command =>\&exec_parser)->grid(  $tab3->Button(-text=>"Test-eNB", -command=>sub{exit}),
$tab3->Button(-text=>"Exit!",-activebackground=>"red",-activebackground=>"red",-command=>sub{exit}),
                                                                 "-", "-",
                                                                -sticky=>'e',
                                                                -ipadx=>25, -ipady=>25,
                                                                -padx=>50, -pady=>50
                                                            );
#=====================================================
# Empty page 4
# TG_Configuration
#=====================================================
my $tab4 = $nb->add('page4', -label=>"TG_Configuration");

$tab4->Button(-text=>"SAITG",-command=>sub{exit})->grid($tab4->Button(-text=>"SmartBit",-command=>sub{exit}),
                                                        $tab4->Button(-text=>"Iperf",-command=>sub{exit}),
                                                        -sticky=>'nsew',
                                                        -ipadx=>25, -ipady=>25,
                                                        -padx=>50, -pady=>50,
                                                       );
#=====================================================
# Empty page 5
# Log Monitor
#=====================================================
my $tab5 = $nb->add("page5", -label=>"Log Monitor");

    $f = $tab5->Frame->pack(-side => 'top', -fill => 'x');

    $tab5->Button(-text => "Exit",-activebackground=>"red",-command => sub { exit; } )->pack(-side => 'bottom',-anchor=>'se',-ipadx=>10, -ipady=>10);
    $tab5->Button(-text => "Save",-activebackground=>"green",-command => \&save_log_file)->pack(-side => 'right',-anchor => 'ne',-ipadx=>10, -ipady=>10);
    $tab5->Button(-text => "Load", -command => \&load_log_file)->pack(-side => 'right', -anchor => 'ne',-ipadx=>10, -ipady=>10);
        $tab5->repeat(1000,\&load_log_file);

#   Create necessary widgets
    $tab5->Label(-textvariable => \$info, -relief => 'ridge')->pack(-side => 'bottom', -fill => 'x');
    $t = $tab5->Scrolled("Text",-scrollbars=>"w",-exportselection => 1)->pack(-side => 'bottom',-fill => 'both', -expand => 1,);

#=====================================================
# Empty page 6
# TC_Result
#=====================================================
    my $tab6 = $nb->add("page6", -label=>"TC_Result");

    $tab6->Button(-text=>"Report - Excel_sheet", -command=>\&report_spread_sheet)->pack( -side=>'top',
                                                                                         -anchor=>'center',
                                                                                         -ipadx => 50, -ipady => 25,
                                                                                         -padx=>500, -pady=>75
                                                                                       );

    $tab6->Button(-text=>"Report - HTML_sheet", -command=>\&report_html_sheet)->pack(   -side=>'top',
                                                                                        -anchor=>'center',
                                                                                        -ipadx => 50, -ipady => 25,
                                                                                        -padx=>500, -pady=>50
                                                                                    );

    $tab6->Button(-text=>"Exit!",-activebackground=>"red", -command=>sub{exit})->pack(  -side=>'bottom',
                                                                                        -anchor=>'se',
                                                                                        -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                                                     );
#=====================================================
#   Empty page 7
#   TTCN-3 
#=====================================================
    my $tab7 = $nb->add("page7", -label=>"TTCN-3");
    $tab7->Button(-text=>"Exit!",-activebackground=>"red", -command=>sub{exit})->pack(  -side=>'bottom',
                                                                                        -anchor=>'se',
                                                                                        -ipadx => 10, -ipady => 10
                                                                                     );
# ================================
    $mw->bind('<Control-o>', [\&open_file]);
    $mw->bind('<Control-s>', [\&save_file]);
    $mw->bind('<Control-e>', [\&edit_file]);


    $types = [ ['XML Files',   '.xml'],
                  ['Perl files', '.pl'],
                  ['Text Files',   '.txt'],
                  ['All Files',   '*'],
                ];

MainLoop;

# ================================================
# $fname;                     #Fetch the selected test case file name
# =========================================================
# sub clear_entry
# {
#    $w->delete('0.0', 'end');
# }
# # =========================================================
sub open_file
{
  $open_fname = $mw->getOpenFile(-filetypes => $types,
                                    -defaultextension => '.xml'
                                   );
    if($open_fname)
    {
#         print qq{You chose to open "$open_fname"\n};
        my @ref = split(/\//,$open_fname);
        $fname = $ref[$#ref];
#         print "From open.pl ::: $fname\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print"Please select the test case file!!!\n";
        exit;
    }
}
# =========================================================
sub exec_parser
{
if (!$sub_routine_flg)
{
#   print "\n\nIn if condition of open.pl....having name in fname::$fname\n\n";
    &xml_parser_execution($fname);
    $sub_routine_flg = 1;
    undef $fname;
#   print "\tIn if part\n\n";
    print "\n\t***** Execution Completed.... Please Select test case from data base ***** ....\n\n";
}
else
{
# #     undef $fname;
#   print "fname in else part in open.pl:: $fname\n";
#   print "\n\n\tsubroutine flag is set in open.pl\n\n";
    &xml_parser_execution($fname);
    undef $fname;
#   print "\tIn else part\n\n";
    print "\n\t***** Execution Completed.... Please Select test case from data base ***** ....\n\n";
}
}
# =========================================================
#### ==Subroutine for log ==####
# load_file :- checks to see what the filename is and loads it if possible
sub load_log_file
{
    $info = "Loading file '$log_filename' ...";
    $t->delete("1.0", "end");
    if (!open(FH, "$log_filename"))
    {
    $t->insert("end", "ERROR: Could not open $log_filename\n");
    return;
    }
    while (<FH>) { $t->insert("end", $_); }
    close (FH);
    $info = "File '$filename' loaded";
}

# save_file :- saves the file using the filename in the entry box.
sub save_log_file
{
    $info = "Saving '$log_filename'";
    open (FH, ">$log_filename");
    print FH $t->get("1.0", "end");
    $info = "Saved...";
}
# =========================================================
sub save_dut_config_file
{
    $info = "Saving '$filename'";
    open (FH, ">$filename");
    print FH $t->get("1.0", "end");
    $info = "Saved.";
}
# =========================================================
sub print_dut_rec()
{
    open (FH, ">/home/SaLTT/DUT_Config.txt")||die" Not able to open DUT_Config.txt file xxxxxxxxxxxxx....\n";
    @key = keys %info;
    foreach $_ (@key)
    {
    print FH "$_:    $info{$_}\n";
#     print "$_:   $info{$_}\n";
    }
}
# =================== Report subroutines ======================================
sub report_spread_sheet
{

}

sub report_html_sheet
{

}
# =========================================================
```

This code works perfectly for creating a GUI and i am performing some actions with this code.

Comment: Pre-declaring variables is very C-like and unnecessary in Perl. Just use `my` when you use them for the first time, and your code will be shorter, more readable, and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a watermark in a frame by using a label instead and setting the image on that; in terms of structural behavior in Tk, frames and labels work just the same (i.e., both are happy to contain other widgets and they don't have lots of behavior of their own to get in the way). Some tinkering with the configuration might be needed to get exactly what you are looking for (e.g., eliminating borders) but that should be easily doable.

If you're using Ttk widgets, you're better off making your own style to apply to the frame IIRC. Style authoring remains a bit of a black art, even with the help of the [tkdocs tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html).

Answer (score 0):

Watermarking of image in tk is not possible. You can use -alpha value to make tk windo transperant. Instead use already processed image.